# Is there a quick way to find the remainder when this determinant is divided by $5$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, determinant, congruences

> Find the remainder when the determinant $\begin{vmatrix} { 2014 }^{ 2014 } & { 2015 }^{ 2015 } & { 2016 }^{ 2016 } \\ { 2017 }^{ 2017 } & { 2018 }^{ 2018 } & { 2019 }^{ 2019 } \\ { 2020 }^{ 2020 } & { 2021 }^{ 2021 } & { 2022 }^{ 2022 } \end{vmatrix}$ is divided by $5$.

I'm aware that this problem has a number-theoretic solution involving congruence relations. But considering that this was asked as a multiple-choice question in a test, what should be the best way to approach problems like this?

The options were $(a)\quad1\quad (b)\quad2\quad (c)\quad3\quad (d)\quad 4$

Comment: @heather No calculators.

Comment: I doubt that you can make use of the multiple-choice nature of the question, since almost all possible answers are present in the options.

Comment: Your best best is to use Fermat's little theorem:  reduce the exponents mod $4$ and the numbers being exponentiated mod $5$.  Then compute the determinant as usual, and then reduce the result mod $5$.

Comment: @BarryCipra Do you see any pattern to compute the determinant easily while starting off?

Comment: @StubbornAtom, I don't.  It's possible there is one, but if I were faced with this on an exam, I wouldn't spend a lot of time trying to find it.

Comment: If you have problems with congruence then you may observe the last digits to find the remainders. But it only works for modulo 5 and 10. So, it's still better to stick to congruence.

Comment: @tatan Yes, thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that, modulo $5$,
 \begin{align}
2014 &\equiv-1, & 2015 & \equiv 0, & 2016 &\equiv 1,\\ 
2017 & \equiv2, & 2018 &\equiv-2, & 2019 &\equiv-1, \\
 2020 &\equiv 0, & 2021 &\equiv 1, & 2022 & \equiv2.
\end{align}
Furthermore $2$ and $-2$ have order $4$ modulo $5$, so the determinant is congruent to
$$\begin{vmatrix}
1 & 0 & 1 \\ 2 & (-2)^2 & -1 \\ 0 & 1 & 2^2
\end{vmatrix}=\begin{vmatrix}
1 & 0 & 1 \\ 2 & -1 & -1 \\ 0 & 1 & -1
\end{vmatrix}=\begin{vmatrix}
1 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & -1 & 2 \\ 0 & 1 & -1
\end{vmatrix}=(-1)^2-2=-1\equiv 4.$$

Comment: Thanks for this, but do you think this can be done alternatively?

Comment: I don't see  what you have in mind. Could you explain more precisely? I just did two things: reduce each element in the determinant modulo $5$, then  one row operation to simplify expansion along the first column

Comment: No I mean is there a solution that does not use congruence?

Comment: Personally, I don't see one. Of course , one can note the last column is  divisible by $3^{2016}$. So what? Except asking a computer algebra system to calculate each element, then the determinant and divide… But it's so much simpler this way (congruences were invented for that).

Comment: @Stub, the question is asking you to evaluate a congruence. Anything you do to solve it is just going to be using congruence, either openly or secretly.

Comment: The answer should be 4 can you help me ?

Comment: @HGSur Note that $4$ and $-1$ are congruent modulo $5:$ $4=-1+5.$

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: @StubbornAtom It can also be done using binomial theorem by writing $2014=2015-1$ and $2016=2015+1$ etc. Also I know I'm three years late but for any future viewers like me who may wish for a solution without explicitly using modular arithmetic...

Comment: @infinite-blank- can you explain further? I am not familiar with modulo arithmetic so I would definitely like to understand the binomial method

Comment: @Aditya for eg. $2014^{2014}=(2015-1)^{2014}=\binom{n}{0}(2015)^{2014}(-1)^0+\binom{n}{1}(2015)^{2013}(-1)^1+...+\binom{n}{n-1}(2015)^1(-1)^{2013}+\binom{n}{n}(2015)^0(-1)^{2014}$ so except the last term all of them are divisible by $5$ ie. the remainder is $1$.