# The remainder when this determinant is divided by 5

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, determinant

The question is  find the remainder when $\begin{vmatrix} { 2014 }^{ 2014 } & { 2015 }^{ 2015 } & { 2016 }^{ 2016 } \\ { 2017 }^{ 2017 } & { 2018 }^{ 2018 } & { 2019 }^{ 2019 } \\ { 2020 }^{ 2020 } & { 2021 }^{ 2021 } & { 2022 }^{ 2022 } \end{vmatrix}$ is divided by 5.
While googling, I found this answer [Is there a quick way to find the remainder when this determinant is divided by $5$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1931365/is-there-a-quick-way-to-find-the-remainder-when-this-determinant-is-divided-by)
but unfortunately I don't have the skill level to understand that answer.
It says I'll have to use Fermat's little theorem(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem) but I can't figure out how to apply it in this question.

Comment: I don't think the answer given in ur link has used Fermat's Little Theorem anywhere.

Comment: @tatanI read in a comment on that question to use Fermat's little theorem.

Comment: There is no need to use Fermat's Little Theorem anywhere. It's because it's modulo 5. Just observe the last digits if u have problems with congruence or Fermat's Little Theorem.

Comment: You can start a bounty to bring our attention to the question. But asking it again is not a way. This is surely a duplicate as @mfl has said.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, you can find the remainder of all the bases, using $a\equiv b \mod m\implies a^n\equiv b^n \mod m$. From there, you can show that $2015^{2015}\equiv2020^{2020}\equiv0\mod5$ and various other results. From there, you can use Fermat's Little Theorem.